# How to do separability analysis in eCognition?

Tags: classification, digital-image-processing, band, ecognition

Can I use eCognition to check which bands are more helpful to separate individual classes and to get output result? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: What is the connection between your ArcGIS tags and your question?

Comment: how matrix error on ecognition. how can help me. mail: es.rad1204@yahoo.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can do this task in eCognition. The process steps are

1. Do segmentation; preferably multiresolution (of scale parameter 5) or chessboard segmentation ( of scale parameter 1; this will useful to understand the pixel values)
2. Now in the Feature View, you can see the Object features >> Layer values >> Mean >> in which your uploaded image layers.
3. Double click on each layer. On the down right corner click the check box,then the values can be seen.
4. You can select which spectral band is useful to detect each classes. You may split the windows by window >> split horizontally >> side by side view. Now update the values of each image layers on different windows. You can compare the results of each band.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you very much, Sandhya!

Comment: eCognition is one of the best classification software. It is useful to complete complex task. Agree?

Comment: Totally agree with it. It seems quite powerful software for classification. Recently, I'm very interested in eCognition. Actually I'm one of the new users of it.

Comment: By the way, how can I get class separability report between the classes, such as M-statistic. I suppose the separability report would be very similar with cross tablulation in accuracy assessment.

Comment: sorry, similar with error matrix, not cross tabulation.

Comment: u can use feature list variables to store the features and export that variable as statistics but with my knowledge one may not get separability report. U can ask this question on eCognition discussion forum.